# Read a line from a file and search it for string (c++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read in a file line by line and search each line for a specific string, but I am having trouble. The file is being read without any issues, but when I try to search each line, nothing seems to happen. The if statement that tests whether the string is found or not gets skipped over. Any idea what is going on here? Thanks!
What I have so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string DECAF="WDCD71";
    string buffer;
    fstream infile("bagging2.txt", ios::in);

    if (infile.fail())
    {
        cout<<"NOPE. NOT WORKING"<<endl;
        exit (1);
    }

    while (getline(infile,buffer))
    {
        if(buffer.find(DECAF)!=string::npos)
        {
            cout<<"FOUND IT!"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample of the text file I am trying to read:

Bagging Schedule
"February 8, 2016"

URNEX
   TABZ
    Brew n Bake "MPN:13-TABZL12-120 Tabz Coffee Brewer Cleaning Tablets, 120 Tablet Jar"    1.00

WDCD71
   LBW
    Brew n Bake Decaffeinated Spicewood Seventy One (pounds)    4.00

OZW
    Glory Bean Coffee Company   Decaffeinated Spicewood Seventy One (12oz bag)  6.00

WRCBRA-PAN
   LBW
    "Stouthaus, LLC"    Brazil Fazenda Pantano Yellow Bourbon/Catuai  (pounds)  8.00
    Liberty Bar Brazil Fazenda Pantano Yellow Bourbon/Catuai  (pounds)  12.00
            20.00
   OZR
    Website - Orders    Brazil Fazenda Pantano Yellow Bourbon/Catuai  (12oz bag)    1.00

OZW
    Whole Foods:Woodlands   Brazil Fazenda Pantano Yellow Bourbon/Catuai  (12oz bag)    12.00
            13.00

Comment: What is the format of your input file?

Comment: Have you tried to look what's in `buffer` with a debugger (or debug output)?

Comment: It is a .txt file with lines of varying length. Some lines may only be 6 characters long, while others go all the way across. I have tried looking at `buffer` with a debugger, but nothing is showing up.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me...  You do have a line in your input file (bagging2.txt) containing WDCD71 don't you?  Wait, I just now saw your edit, I'll try your data...

Comment: Haha, yes, I do have a line containing WDCD71. Perhaps the problem is just specific to Xcode. Thanks for checking.

Comment: I just tried the code again with the data in your question and it still works.  The only thing I can think of is that the file containing the correct data has a different name than bagging2.txt?

Comment: Just double checked and everything looks right. The file is being read, but the if statement isn't getting executed. I guess I'll try to find some sort of workaround. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugger. Also check hexdump to make sure bagging2.txt has "WDCD71"

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it took me this long to figure it out, but after much searching and experimenting, I have found that my issues here are a result of the way the .txt file was encoded. It was encoded as a UTF-16 file, which, as I found, must be opened in binary mode in order to properly be read. When I tried using files that had been encoded as Windows Formatted Text, the program worked perfectly. Thanks y'all!